# Rest to Azure SQL database integration service

Tags: rest, azure, azure-sql-database

Hei

I have a simple scenario, where I have an on-premise system that hosts a rest api. I what based on data in that rest to fill data into a Auzure SQL database using some type of synchronization job. I just unsure of the best method to do this? Can one use Azure Data Factory for this? What other services can do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Azure app services is a background task service called Azure Web Jobs

Here are links to help you get started:

Azure App Service Overview: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-value-prop-what-is/

Overview from another website: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2423911

Azure Web Jobs introduction: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/